# Launching threads from within while loop, what happens?

Tags: java, multithreading, while-loop

I want to have a while loop that launches a thread on each loop,

I am using the following to launch the thread, do I need to have a unique identifier for each thread or becuase it is launching from different loops will it launch ok, or will it overwrite the previous launch as they are using the same identifier?

```
while(x<y){
Runnable r = new Rule1("neil", 2, 0);
new Thread(r).start();
x++;
}
```

Comment: What on earth do you think will go wrong?

Comment: Questions like this you should try first before asking.  If you are confused or want explanations of your results, that's fine, but questions like "will this work" are better accomplished by running it and seeing.

Comment: Also, there is no logical or illogical reason to expect anything to be shared.  There isn't even a logical explanation of _what_ he thinks will be shared.

Comment: Seriously consider an [ExecutorService] (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) instead of spawning a bunch of your own threads.

Comment: I tried to test it myself but as it launches the exact same thread i wasn't able to come up with a way to verify if it was running multiple threads or just the one since they all have the same outputs

Comment: The first thing to do with a question like this is to think about what the compiler and runtime will do with your statements.

Comment: most likely you starting with Threads in Java. Keep a copy of 'java concurrency in practise' . It is the book most useful to learn concurrency.

Comment: @Jayan, I'm so tired of seeing people post telling someone to read JCIP. I've seen people post answers and comments talking about JCIP and they still have no idea what they are talking about when it comes to concurrency. There are no silver bullets, including JCIP, and trying to force complex ideas on a confused mind will only confuse it further. Just my rant for the day.

Comment: Agree.+1. There more useful books to start with..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will work fine.

Your threads do not have any identifiers at all.
The `r` variable is a normal (and temporary) variable; you are passing its value to the `Thread` constructor.

The runtime isn't even aware of the variable.

Comment: SLaks is right in response to the question of each thread not having identifiers... They would be considered anonymous (i.e there is no reference to the thread that is within scope for you to access...). This means that every time you go through the loop you are unable to obtain a reference to the previous instance of thread.

Answer (score 4):

It will launch multiple threads. The only "unique identifier" for the thread is the ID returned by `Thread.getId()`, and you don't get to assign that. Even the thread name doesn't need to be unique. In other words, there's no unique identifier which is being reused here.

Certainly the fact that you're assigning the `Thread` reference to the same variable on each iteration doesn't mean the threads will care in the slightest.

Answer (score 0):

While you do not need to create a unique identifier for each thread (framework will take care of it) it is best practice if at all possible to name your threads in relation to what they are doing so that when you begin debugging via logs/jvisualvm you are aware of the threads purpose.